# updating dom text based on click in jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

My Simple HTML Structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
<p id="5">
    My Text Qoted Here - 
    <span class="author">Author </span>
          <br>
          <span class="uptext">20</span>
          <img class="im" class="upimg" 
          src="http://bgathinktank.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/vote-button.jpg" />
          <img class="im" class="downimg"
          src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_XeuZ1yDnv4Q/TSUkAT6T1dI/AAAAAAAADR8/nPHP4JvVxy8/s1600/vote.jpg" />
          <span class="downtext">5</span>
          </p>
</body>
</html>
```

as can be seen there are two images, and i want to change the count of the image based on which image is clicked.

i write the following jquery code for it:

```
$(function() {
 $(".upimg").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("here1");
        curr_val = $(this).closest(".uptext").text();
        nos = parseInt(curr_val, 10) + 1;
        $(this).closest(".uptext").text(nos);
    });

    $(".downimg").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("here2");
        curr_val = $(this).closest(".downtext").text();
        nos = parseInt(curr_val, 10) + 1;
        $(this).closest(".downtext").text(nos);
    });

});
```

But it does not seem to respond. 
**You can find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Bu4U/1/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `<img>` tags have two class attributes:

```
<img class="im" class="upimg"
```

Try changing that to

```
<img class="im upimg"
```

Also, the `closest()` method returns the closest *parent* element, not an adjacent sibling, so to find the correct `uptext` element, you need to use:

```
$(this).prev().text()
```

Comment: ...and `closest` needs to change to `prevAll(":first")`

Comment: or prevAll(":first"). Although, prev() is a simpler selector so should run several nano seconds faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use 2 class attribute
you have to do like that

```
<img class="im upimg" 
          src="http://bgathinktank.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/vote-button.jpg" />
```